# Using Pure CSS to Access and Style Span Content

Tags: html, css

I'm working with a dynamic data table, and I need the text color in the availability column to change dynamically depending on the package status from a generic database. Specifically, I want "In Stock" to be green and "Out of Stock" to be red. Here's a simplified version of the HTML structure:

```
<div class="fd-datatable">
    <div class="innerScrollContainer">
        <div class="row" role="row" tabindex="0" aria-rowindex="1" aria-label="row">
            <div aria-colindex="1" role="gridcell">
                <!-- ... other columns ... -->
                <div aria-colindex="4" role="gridcell">
                    <span>In Stock</span>
                </div>
                <!-- ... other columns ... -->
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- ... other rows ... -->
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I access the text within the  tag, for each row so that I can change its color, **using only CSS**?

Comment: Please don't edit questions to change your code or your question after answers have arrived... especially not after you have accepted one. Instead, ask a new question if you have a different question.

Comment: Your spans should have classes applied in addition to the text values. This is standard practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do this but here is a little hack to achieve what you want. It relies on the fact that both text won't take the same width so I will use the size as a condition to apply a different coloration.

Here is a simplified example. The `90px` is what control the condition, you need to adjust it based on you real code

```css
span {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #0000;
  background: 
    linear-gradient(green 0 0) 0/calc(90px - 100%) 1%,
    linear-gradient(red   0 0) 0/calc(100% - 90px) 1%;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
          background-clip: text;
}
```

```html
<span>In Stock</span>
<span>Out of Stock</span>
<span>Out of Stock</span>
<span>In Stock</span>
```

I have detailed article where I explain such a trick and more: https://css-tricks.com/responsive-layouts-fewer-media-queries/

Comment: Thanks, the solution offered effectively resolved my concern. Employing a condition based on the width of the text to apply distinct coloration proved to be successful.

Comment: I have a quick question. If I utilize a ::before pseudo-element, is it possible to make its color match that of the adjacent span?

Comment: @koreangirl it depends on the structure, show me how the code looks like

Comment: something like this:
<span class="w-full flex-shrink-0"> 
::before 
Available
</span>

Answer (score -2):

I understand that this differs from what you have in your post, and that you already have a solution. But this may be a decent alternative as well, given that you have control over rendering the DOM.

I am assuming that wanting this done in pure CSS is driven by wanting the least amount of manual alterations to an element to get it to show how you want. Personally what I like to do in this instance is instead of filling the span with the text and trying to have the functionality driven by the text entered, I would make a class specific to each instance, and have the all the functionality *including* the text be driven off of that.

So here I have a *pure CSS* example of this functionality. Given that when you are rendering your DOM elements, instead of applying the text you need for each one, you apply the class you need for each one.

```css
span {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 20px
}
span.no-stock:before {
  color: red;
  content: "Out Of Stock"
}
span.in-stock:before {
  color: green;
  content: "In Stock"
}
```

```html
<span class="in-stock"></span>
<span class="no-stock"></span>
<span class="no-stock"></span>
<span class="in-stock"></span>
```